# How to create DynamoDB table with list and map

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I'm new to DynamoDB. I am trying to create DynamoDB with SAM project. I know I can only use "S", "N", "B" for AttributeType but I want to use like the below.

```
{
  "TableName": "xyz",
  "KeySchema": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "uid",
      "KeyType": "HASH"
    }
  ],
  "AttributeDefinitions": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "uid",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "email",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "postal_code",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "bookmark",
      "AttributeType": "L" ← (I want to use List)
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "children",
      "AttributeType": "M" ← (I want to use Map)
    }
  ],
  "ProvisionedThroughput": {
    "ReadCapacityUnits": 2,
    "WriteCapacityUnits": 2
  }
```

It is my table.json and I want to create the table with this aws command.

```
aws dynamodb --profile local --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 create-table --cli-input-json file://./testdata/table.json
```

How do you have list data and map data with DynamoDB?

Comment: Just know that you do not have to add all of the attributes you plan to have on items in the table definition. Each item can have its own set of attributes. The only ones an item has to have are the ones that make up the primary key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean I just define primary key in the JSON and just put an object that has all data I want to put into DynamoDB from my code on lambda?

Comment: Yes. DynamoDB does not enforce a schema beyond the primary key. It means that one item might have attribute A, but another item does not even have it. It is very flexible this way.

Comment: I could put all data into DynamoDB. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is best to do it when you add items to the table. DynamoDB has a flexible schema and therefore does not enforce a schema beyond the primary key. Item A might have attribute1, but item B might omit that attribute.

When you create your table, just add the primary key (either partition key or partition key + sort key) and that's it. Then add your items with the data typed attributes that item needs.

Answer (score -1):

I think `SS` can be used for `List` where SS stands for `String Set`. e.g.:

```
...
{
  "AttributeName": "bookmark",
  "AttributeType": "SS"
},
...
```

Ref: [DynamoDB Supported Data Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html)

Comment: SS is not an accepted data type in cloudformation templating

Comment: @hyprstack if it's not an accepted datatype then howcome AWS is referencing that in their official documentation? Have you tried SS in cloudformation templating??

Comment: Yup. Aws documentation isn't always up to date with what you can actually do. Dynamodb might acccept SS data type, but at the time of my comment, it was not accepted in cloudformation templating